# ebtables is causing packet loss

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, ebtables

I am using AlmaLinux 8 on a dedicated server and hosting VPSes using KVM.
Applying ebtables rules on those VPSes is causing packet loss issue.

Bridge chain: v1001, entries: 1, policy: DROP
-p IPv4 -s 00:xx:xx:52:69:ac --ip-src 192.168.122.204 -j ACCEPT

Bridge chain: v1001IPV6, entries: 0, policy: DROP

Bridge chain: v1001ARPIN, entries: 2, policy: ACCEPT
-p ARP --arp-ip-src 192.168.122.204 --arp-mac-src 00:xx:xx:52:69:ac -j ACCEPT
-p ARP -j DROP

There are around 100 VPSes hosted.
Applying/loading rules for all those VPSes all at once would cause issues ?

I also receive this :

ebtables -L 'v1001ARPIN'
ebtables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): chain `v1001ARPIN' in table` filter' is incompatible, use 'nft' tool